# Why is the data being displayed many times over the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to set up a kind of search engine connected to an API. It takes the user input and gives back the information from the API. In the future there  should be a "dynamic" amount of input fields but for the moment I am working with a fixed amount of five. The loop takes the amount of fields and calls the API that amount of times with that input.

I tried placing a constant (i.e. 5) in the loop but still, the funny part is that with 3 it of course calls the app three times but outputs 6 fields, and with 2 it calls the API 2 times but outputs three rows so it seems that it does not obey the loop but something else. Meanwhile in the console (with log) I can see that the API is properly called only the times defined by the loop so I believe something goes wrong at the `$.getJSON` level

The problem is at the end a table is created with 15 rows instead of the expected 5 (one row for every input). Why do you think this is happening?

Thanks in advance

```html
<form name="inputform" method="get" width="50">
  <input type="text" name="field0" id="field0" size="50">
  <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" size="50">
  <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" size="50">
  <input type="text" name="field3" id="field3" size="50">
  <input type="text" name="field4" id="field4" size="50">
</form>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Preference</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="getInfo" type="button" value="Submit" /><br/>
```

```js
var customURL = "http://apitest.com/test/";
var customURL1 = '';

$('#getInfo').click(function() {
  $('#table tr').not(':first').remove();
  var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var table = document.getElementById('table');

  if (localStorage.myJSON !== undefined) {
    var myJSON = JSON.parse(localStorage.myJSON);
  }
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++) {
    customURL1 = customURL + document.getElementById('field' + i + '').value;
    console.log(customURL1);

    $.getJSON(customURL1, function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          html += '<tr><td>' + data.sample_list.id + '</td><td>' + data.sample_list.name + '</td><td>' + data.sample_list.age + '</td><td>' + data.sample_list.preference + '</td></tr>';
          $('#table tr').first().after(html);
```

Comment: Your JavaScript is cut off in the middle.

Comment: Aside from any duplication issues in the logic you should be aware that making AJAX requests in a loop is not scalable at all. I'd suggest you look at aggregating all the data in to a single request.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan That is a possiblity I was considering, so it is better to pack all of the input in one request and get one JSON answer which then can be properly processed. Is my understanding right?

Comment: That's correct, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you get an AJAX response, you're appending the response to the `html` variable, and then adding that after the first row of the table. Since the `html` variable already contains the results from the previous responses, and they were insert into the table already, you get duplicates.

Instead of concatenating the new row to `html`, just insert the new row directly into the table.

```
$.getJSON(customURL1, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#table tr').first().after('<tr><td>' + data.sample_list.id + '</td><td>' + data.sample_list.name + '</td><td>' + data.sample_list.age + '</td><td>' + data.sample_list.preference + '</td></tr>');
```